# How much energy is needed to create an electron?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, mass-energy

I know how to calculate the electrostatic energy of a sphere (it has a well defined radius). But how can I calculate the electrostatic energy of an electron as it is a point particle? By electrostatic energy of a charge distribution we generally mean the energy needed to place the charges where they are. (In short energy needed to create the system).

So, how much energy I need to create an [electron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want to complete the other answer by addressing the difference of a charge distribution made statistically up by a huge number of electrons , and what an electron means:

At the level of [elementary particles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle), one of which is the electron, there  are no charge distributions, as elementary particles are point particles, and charge is a quantized quantity that is an attribute of the electron, like spin and its mass that cannot be further  cut up. In the case of a proton, there exists a charge distribution given by the distributions of the quarks that compose it: the quarks are the elementary particles in this case.

A lone electron cannot be created because of lepton number conservation, it has to come with an antielectron or be part of a decay process, like the decay of the muon where the electron number is conserved by the creation of an antineutrino-electron.

Comment: There is no way to create a elektron without a positron. So You have to invest 1022 keV anyway. But you get that energy back when the positron decayces with some elektron. This means, you cannot "create" an electron at all, what you get is just a pair for a small fraction of a second, which vanishes nearly imediately.

Comment: @Georg  you do get a single electron from a muon- decay, as I say in my answer. Creation is a moot word. Anyway my answer should be read in parallel with the other answer. atoms have a lot of electrons around them no? no positrons around either.

Comment: continued: at the big bang before atoms were formed there might have been the same number but because of (not explained yet)  CP violation we ended up with protons and electrons.

Comment: This article says,''The problem of the infinite self-energies of elementary charged particles is still unresolved.''
http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node56.html

Comment: It is a classical physics based paper. The problem is "solved" in quantum physics by postulating the quantized nature of charge and charged elementary particles and ignoring the classical construction arguments. Similar to solving the 1/r potential problem with the quantized solutions of the Schrodinger equation, the r=0 is meaningless. In the standard model the charges are identified with the group representation  parameters describing mathematically the set of particles ( observed experimentally).

Comment: Okey,I got it.This seem to be technical problem.Thanks for your ans.It was helpfull.I got this paper just now..http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node44.html

Comment: Yes, if you delve into the calculations that is the way it is solved. At conceptual level though the group structure assignment of charge  ,+/- 1/3 and +/-2/3 for quarks and -1 for electron contain the problem at a postulated level.

Answer (score 4):

The rest mass energy of an electron is 511 keV. So this is how much energy is required to create an electron, at rest, and which is not in an electromagnetic field. You need not be concerned about the point-like nature of the electron, that just makes it simpler to calculate the difference in ths energy (if necessary) caused by any *external* electric potential $\phi$ where the electron is. The electrostatic energy is just $-e \phi$.

In practice it is a bit more complicated depending on how you intend to create your electron because of conservation laws. i.e. charge, lepton number and momentum must be conserved, as well as energy, so the negative charge must have been taken from somewhere else or a positively charged particle must also have been created.

In the case of [pair production](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production), a photon can produce an electron, but it needs to interact with a nucleus to conserve momentum and must also produce a positron to conserve charge and lepton number. In this case the minimum energy required for the photon is the rest mass energy of the electron plus the same rest mass energy for the positron, (i.e. 1022 keV), and even more if it turns out that these particles have kinetic energy.

Comment: $\phi$  comes from which source?
can the electron have an potential created by its own field?

Comment: @Paul No. The potential energy arises from interaction with external fields.

Comment: In the question I have assumed that there is no external field and i bring some charge(equal to the charge in an electron) from somewhere and make the electron.

Comment: Okey.The energy I need to make the electron is stored as mass in the electron.

Comment: 'Paul plus its kinetic energy plus the energy needed to create any other necessary particles.

Comment: This article says,''The problem of the infinite  self-energies of elementary charged particles is still  unresolved.'' http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node56.html

Comment: Thanks for your ans.It was helpfull.
By the way i got an article to read ,the problem really is very technical though.http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node475.html#section:selfenergy

Answer (score 1):

If you try to concentrate separate electric charges repelling each other with the Coulomb forces, you would never succeed because that would require infinite amount of energy. That means if electron is charge concentrated into a point, it is not made of smaller parts but is an elementary particle and its rest energy is not electrostatic. This is the common viewpoint. (It is very unlikely but theoretically at very small distances the repulsive force could be weaker than what the Coulomb law says so finite energy would be sufficient to squash the charges into small region or a point. Part of rest energy would be electrostatic then.)